# Yahoo Pipes to enrich RSS descriptions dynamically with ${title} variable?

Tags: xml, rss, pipe, yahoo, yql

In Yahoo Pipes, By using the Regex module I can replace item.link .* with a url such as       https://www.google.com/webhp#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=**${title}**

What this accomplishes is say that the title of the feed is "Barack Obama visits Oklahoma", the title will now link to the google search term "Barack Obama visits Oklahoma" using the ${title} variable.

But what I would like to be able to do is add scripting to the description, so that I can do things like embed a youtube video with the rss output of http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?max-results=1&alt=rss&q=**${title}**  and show images of the related title with a flickr rss output of http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=**${title}**&format=rss_200

Is there a way to accomplish this? Can it be accomplished with Yahoo's YQL module for Pipes? Are there other services that can perform this function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

YQL has an execute method which can run JavaScript on the output to transform it into the desired format. Here are a few examples:

```
<execute><![CDDATA[
// request.url == 'http://some_web_service_or_feed
// This is the same as 'y.rest(request.url).get();'
var returned_response = request.get();
...
]]>
</execute>

<execute><![CDATA[
// Include the OAuth libraries from oauth.net
y.include("http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/oauth.js");
y.include("http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/sha1.js");

// Collect all the parameters
var encodedurl = request.url;
var accessor = { consumerSecret: cs, tokenSecret: ""};
var message = { action: encodedurl, method: "GET", parameters: [["oauth_consumer_key",ck],["oauth_version","1.0"]]};
OAuth.setTimestampAndNonce(message);

// Sign the request
OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);

try {
   // get the content from service along with the OAuth header, and return the result back out
    response.object = request.contentType('application/xml').header("Authorization", OAuth.getAuthorizationHeader("netflix.com", message.parameters)).get().response;
    } catch(err) {
    response.object = {'result':'failure', 'error': err};
    }
]]>
</execute>
```

**References**

- [YQL Code Tutorials](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_code_tutorials.html)
- [myql/table.md | YQL Open Data Table Docs](https://github.com/josuebrunel/myql/blob/master/docs/table.md)
- [yql/lorem.ipsum.xml | YQL Lorem Ipsum Service Call Example](https://github.com/bcantoni/yql/blob/master/lorem.ipsum.xml)