# How to force xml-outlining / pretty printing in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, xml, iframe, colors, pretty-print

An `xml`-file is loaded from a *different domain* within an `iframe` in a Webkit/Chrome browser and the HTTP Content-Type is set to `application/xml`.
Generally `xml` would be colored and pretty-printed, using a built-in browser content-script. In the `iframe`, the same xml-file will only show the text within the tags and no colored outline, as would be expected with browser-scripts turned off.

**Browser:**
[image]

**Iframe:**
[image]
(*different content*)

**Response headers:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 29 Aug 2013 08:52:55 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Cookie
Content-Length: 154
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=10000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` to the response-header didn't change anything.

**Update: HTML**:

```
<form id="api_output" target="iframepostform" action="https://example.com/api/"
     method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">....
     <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>

<iframe class="clearfix" src="" name="iframepostform" 
      id="iframepostform" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
```

What is the simplest solution to fix this, without abandoning iframes and resorting to XHR requests?

Comment: the url of the iframe is of an xml file?

Comment: @dandavis: Oh Thanks, for mentioning that. Please see the revised post.

Comment: I know this is an old post but do you have solution for this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use Yahoo Pipes or YQL as a proxy formatter service. Here are some examples:

- [How to get the formatted view of YQL as result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588736/)
- [Yahoo Pipes to enrich RSS descriptions dynamically with ${title} variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776932/yahoo-pipes-to-enrich-rss-descriptions-dynamically-with-title-variable/18708190#18708190)